# Can you store tables for reuse in a T-SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay, so I have this T-SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT RentalNo) as Count 
FROM 
    RoomRental AS rr 
    LEFT JOIN 
        RoomLinks AS r 
        On (r.RoomNo1 = rr.RoomNo OR r.RoomNo2 = rr.RoomNo) 
        AND r.CostCentreNo = rr.CostCentreNo
WHERE Cancelled = 0 
    AND (rr.RoomNo = @RN OR r.RoomNo2 = @RN OR r.RoomNo1 = @RN) 
    AND rr.CostCentreNo = @CCN 
    AND StartDate = @StartDate
    AND DATEADD(minute,0-SetupTime,StartTime) < @EndBlock 
    AND DATEADD(minute,BreakdownTime,EndTime) > @StartBlock)
```

Is there any way I can store `SELECT *`, of it, and then quickly (without applying the statement again), get the `RentalNos`, or apply another `AND` to the `WHERE` clause?

Note, this is just an example of my SQL query, I currently have a loop going around, as it goes through all time blocks, (after first querying the first ending).

Basically, there is a lot of similar SQL query repetition. And it would be great If I could store once and manipulate that instead.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: please add what you have tried to store this sql's output.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'store tables in a query', you may want a [common table expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `SELECT INTO` and store the results in a temporary table (the # prefix is used for a temporary table)

```
SELECT yourcols, ...
INTO #table
FROM yourtables...
```

Then you can reference #table just like any other physically stored table, join to it, etc.

Comment: +1 Just an addition - a temporary table's lifetime lasts until the current login session terminates or statement batch completes, unless you `DROP TABLE` on it first.

Comment: This won't work for what the OP is asking. They are talking about arbitrarily retrospectively changing the `WHERE` or `SELECT` clauses. Which is of course not possible.

Comment: Why not? He can just add extra predicates when querying against the #table.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. exactly what I was looking for! Hats off to you, and Stackoverflow! Its such a great place for a fast answer, when google isnt making sense :D

Comment: As long as the initial query brings back all the columns that they want to later add to the select list or where clause yes. But the question the OP asked was can I run *this* query which doesn't.

Comment: I can change the query to work, its not a problem. Was just wondering if the concept was possible :). I now have it working like i want, saving a lot of computation (even though it took only 0.00 seconds in the test environment anyway) This did answer my question. cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a temporary table by doing the following

```
SELECT *
  INTO #temp_table
  FROM etc.
```

Or specifically,

```
SELECT *
  INTO #temp_table
  FROM RoomRental AS rr LEFT JOIN RoomLinks AS r 
    ON (r.RoomNo1 = rr.RoomNo OR r.RoomNo2 = rr.RoomNo) 
   AND r.CostCentreNo = rr.CostCentreNo
 WHERE Cancelled = 0 
   AND (rr.RoomNo = @RN OR r.RoomNo2 = @RN OR r.RoomNo1 = @RN) 
   AND rr.CostCentreNo = @CCN;
```

Then you can execute all your queries against `#temp_table` by using

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT RentalNo) as Count 
  FROM #temp_table
 WHERE StartDate = @StartDate             
   AND DATEADD(minute,0-SetupTime,StartTime) < @EndBlock 
   AND DATEADD(minute,BreakdownTime,EndTime) > @StartBlock)
```

for each set of dates that you want to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for an exact illustration of how to achieve what I want :)!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Temporary Tables (plenty of info on here and the rest of the net).

They can be queried and INSERTED into just like a normal table.